# How to git rebase only changed files

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I'd like to do a git rebase of a repo of HTML files.  I have a repo that looks like:

```
-- A -- B 
   \
    \-- C -- D -- E -- F
```

I'd like to rebase F onto B, but I have the problem that I don't want C.  C introduced a change that reflowed the text in **ALL** of the HTML files.  I only want the changes from D, E, and F for the files that changed in those commits.

So, in other words, I'd like:

```
-- A -- B -- D' -- E' -- F'
```

EXCEPT: I want the last commit to include the files from F that are returned from `git diff --name-only C..F`, and the rest of the files from B.

The thing that doesn't work for me is:

```
git rebase --onto B D F
```

Because I have to do a messy merge, and manually pick which files I want.  I could add `-X theirs` but I get the files from C that I don't want.

So, my crappy not git way of doing it is to just create one new custom commit on top of B, where I copy in the files from F that are in `git diff --name-only C..F`.

Is there a better git way to do this?

(For reference, here's how I do it without fully using git):

```
git diff --name-only C..F | xargs -I{} -n1 sh -c "git show F:{} > {}"
```

Comment: Have you tried using git cherry-pick?

Comment: git cherry pick has the same problem - unless you can select just the files you want to cherry pick (perhaps you can, I just don't know).

Comment: Your rebase that excludes `C` but keeps `D` through `F` should be `git rebase --onto B C F`, not `git rebase --onto D F`.  If that includes files you didn't want, though, that means you don't want everything that's in `D` through `F`, which is contrary to your initial claim.

Answer (score 2):

First, `git cherry-pick -n C`.  The `-n` means it will do the cherry pick but not commit it.  Then make whatever modifications you like and commit.  Let's call this new commit `C1`.

Then `git rebase --onto C1 C F`.  Note that the range is *exclusive*. It will rebase from, but not including, C. The result is D to F.  This makes more sense when you're working with branches like `git rebase --onto master this that`.